# The size of pdf is shown 0 when attached to gmail

Tags: android, pdf, email-attachments

```
String emailAddress[] = {""};

    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(externalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "com.example.pdf/sample.pdf"));

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddress);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
    emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
```

The message shown in logcat is:

```
gMail Attachment URI: file:///mnt/sdcard/com.example.pdf/sample.pdf
gMail type: application/pdf
gmail name: sample.pdf
gmail size: 0
```

The problem is that the size of sample pdf is 0, so the pdf is not sent as an attachment in the email. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How are you saving the pdf on that directory?

If you are using the `getExternalStorageDirectory` (i'm assuming you are), that pdf is private to your application, and can't be accessed by the email app.

If you need to keep that file private to your application, and still be able to share via email, use a `ContentProvider` :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

If you can keep that file on a shared directory, you should use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: The pdf is stored in the sd card and I have used the permission Write_External_Storage

Comment: Are you copying the file to the sdcard using a filemanager application, or downloading the file with your app and saving it on the sdcard?

Comment: The problem is how the file was saved on the sdcard. If your app saved the file using `getExternalDirectory` to get the directory, the email app won't have permission to read the file.