# Android download and display pdf from url

Tags: android

I am getting an .pdf file from a chat and I want to download it and display it using acrobat reader. Following is my code

```
 public void showPDF(String pdf)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.i("pic", "  * * * in showPdf" + pdf);

                String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
                folder.mkdir();
                String pdf_name = pdf.replace(".pdf", "");
                pdf_name = pdf_name.replace("/fileupload/data/chat/", "");
                File file = new File(folder, pdf_name + ".pdf");
                try
                {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("pic", "  * * * ready to download");
                new DownloadFile(file, Functions.getServiceProtocol() + Functions.getServiceDomain() + pdf, pdf_name).execute();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("pic", " CATCH * * * in showPdf");
            }
        }
      } 



  private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
        {
            private String fileURL, pdfname;
            private File directory;
            private ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(CameraWebview.this);

            public DownloadFile(File d, String f, String n)
            {
                directory = d;
                fileURL = f;
                pdfname = n;
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.i("pic", " TRY * * * download file");
                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                    URL u = new URL(fileURL);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();

                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;

                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        f.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }

                    f.flush();
                    f.close();

                    try
                    {
                         Log.i("pic", " TRY * * * calling displayPdf");
                         displayPdf(pdfname);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.i("pic", " CATCH * * * calling displayPdf");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
                dlg.setMessage("Downloading File ...");
                dlg.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
            {
                super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (dlg.isShowing())
                    dlg.dismiss();
            }
        }

      public void displayPdf(String pdf_name)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.i("pic", " TRY * * * ready to show pdf");
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pdf/" + pdf_name + ".pdf");
                PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
               Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.i("pic", " TRY * * * here is the pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("pic", " CATCH * * * show pdf file" + e.toString());
            }
```

It always say "Corrupted file". I checked the url I am using for it and it's fine. Also my app is Ice Cream Sandwitch. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: i don't understand why you create a new File object in displayPdf. Why not use the existing file, given that it is where you write the pdf in the first place?

Comment: also, did you looked at the file in your device ?

Comment: yes, it's alwya 20KB corrupted file

Comment: out of how much ? (and that doesn't answer the first question, which basically may suggest that you are not opening the file you are writing to)

Comment: Where should I open the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `DownloadFile(File d, String f, String n)`, how do you get the directory?

If you are using the `getExternalStorageDirectory` (i'm assuming you are), that pdf is private to your application, and can't be accessed by other applications.

If you need to keep that file private to your application, and still be able to open using another application, use a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)

If you can keep that file on a shared directory, you should use [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to get the path to save the file, and later on to retrieve the file URI.

This problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015233/the-size-of-pdf-is-shown-0-when-attached-to-gmail/13015944#13015944) one, hence the similar answer.

This should solve the problem:

Inside `showPDF`:

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
```

Inside `displayPdf`

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/pdf/" + pdf_name + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Can you log the `extStorageDirectory` string? That way you know where the file is saved on the device.

Comment: It's storing to /mnt/sdcard/Download and it's reading from there

Comment: Can u open that file using a file explorer Application like ESFileExplorer or Astro?

Comment: No. I see the file name there and it's lawys 20KB which is less than what it is. And when I try to open it, it saya, ERROR, The document can not be opened because it is not a valid PDF

Comment: There's a problem with the download then. Is there any specific reason you are using `HttpURLConnection` instead of `URLConnection`. Also, dou you need `setDoOutput(true)`?

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS! ICS is not supporting HttpURLConnection. I used URLConnection and it worked!! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I still believe it's a problem with setDoOutput and/or setRequestMethod, but there was no specific reason to use HttpURLConnection in this case.

Comment: Got it. I saw similar post using HttpURLConnection and ICS. So I jumped on a conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using setDoOutput(true) after setRequestMethod("GET").

setDoOutput(true) sets your request method to POST automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        theurl = new URL(url);                       
                        InputStream in = null;
                        File dst = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/file.pdf");
                            try {
                                in = theurl.openStream();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }               
                            OutputStream out = null;
                        try {
                            out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                             // Transfer bytes from in to out
                             try {
                                byte[] buf = new byte[100000];
                                int len;
                            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                              out.write(buf, 0, len);
                             }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                             try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                             try {
                            out.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```